# бесконечный переворот матрицы на 90,-90,0 Java

Tags: java, матрицы

Напишите программу, которая загружает матрицу и выполняет указанные преобразования указанного массива на 90, -90, 90 градусов. Преобразования будут введены в 0, -1,1. Ввод другого номера завершает обработку текущего задания.
Моя матрица не сохраняет данные с предыдущей матрицы, то есть выводит:

Переворот
1

```
3 6 9 
2 5 8 
1 4 7
```

Переворот
1

```
3 6 9 
2 5 8 
1 4 7
```

А мне нужно:

input:

```
Ввод строк: 3
Ввод столбцов: 3
```

output:

```
Matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9

input: 
Переворот
1

output: 
3 6 9
2 5 8
1 4 7

input: 
Переворот
1

output: 
9 8 7 
6 5 4 
3 2 1

input: 
Переворот
0

output: 
9 8 7 
6 5 4 
3 2 1
```

---

```
public class Transformace {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ввод строк");
        int pr = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ввод столбцов");
        int ps = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[pr][ps];
        Matrix(array);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Переворот");
            int turn = sc.nextInt();
            if (turn == 1) {
                Pocitani(turnToLeft(array));
            } else if (turn == -1) {
                Pocitani(turnToRight(array));
            } else if (turn == 0) {
                Pocitani(array);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    public static int[][] Matrix(int[][] array) {
        int s = 0;
        System.out.println("Matrix");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = s + 1;
                s = s + 1;
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[][] turnToRight(int[][] array) {
//        System.out.println("Rotovana matice");
        int result[][] = new int[array[0].length][array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                result[j][array.length - i - 1] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[][] turnToLeft(int[][] array) {
//        System.out.println("Rotovana matice");
        int result[][] = new int[array[0].length][array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                result[array[i].length - j - 1][i] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void Pocitani(int[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь с этим.

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: моя матрица не сохраняет данные с предыдущей матрицы, то есть выводит Переворот1
3 6 9 
2 5 8 
1 4 7 
Переворот1
3 6 9 
2 5 8 
1 4 7        Прошу помочь с этим

Comment: В методах `turnToXXX` возвращайте не `result`, а `array`, предварительно скопировав все из `result` в `array`

Comment: Я не понимаю, можете написать по подробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Переворот");
    int turn = sc.nextInt();
    if (turn == 1) {
        array = turnToLeft(array);
        Pocitani(array);
    } else if (turn == -1) {
        array = turnToRight(array);
        Pocitani(array);
    } else if (turn == 0) {
        Pocitani(array);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: хм.. А минусы за что?

Comment: Благодарю вас за правильный ответ.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, хейтеры :)